# Правильно вывести данные на страницу

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно правильно получить ответ от бд.

У меня имеется следующее в `ProfileController`:

```
$amount = DB::table('history_of_conclusions')->where('id_user', '=', $user_id)->get('amount');

$id_game = DB::table('history_of_conclusions')->where('id_user', '=', $user_id)->get('id_game');

$date = DB::table('history_of_conclusions')->where('id_user', '=', $user_id)->get('date');
```

Но в ответ прилетает это:

```
[{"amount":100},{"amount":1000}]

[{"id_game":87027154},{"id_game":87027154}]

[{"date":"10.03.2022"},{"date":"11.03.2022"}]
```

Я хочу сопоставить эти данные, чтобы выглядело так:

```
100 87027154 10.03.2022

1000 87027154 11.03.2022
```

Понимаю, что можно сделать как-то через `@foreach`

Comment: Вопрос - зачем получать данные тремя запросами если можно получить их же __одним запросом__?

Comment: их нужно получать разбитыми запросами, для отображения в разных частях шаблона

Comment: @Mark_Markov Сделайте один запрос, а затем разделите данные из него на части. Вам может помочь метод [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: Получать их надо одним запросом и переиспользовать в разных частях шаблона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получайте данные одним запросом:

```php
$rows = DB::table('history_of_conclusions')->where('id_user', '=', $user_id)->get(['amount', 'id_game', 'date']);
```